Plotting a set of equations
I have two following eqs:
$S = a M^2 + \beta + \alpha Log[a M^2]$
$t =\lambda^5 M^5 (3 + \lambda^2 M^2)/
 3\delta (1+\lambda^2 M^2)^2$
where a, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\delta$ and are constant parameters. I want to plot S versus t by combining two eqs. Is there any specific code or plot type to do this in mathematica?

This appears to be a straight-up parametrization of S and t, each given explicitly in terms of M. There's no equation-solving involved at all. Doesn't that seem the case to you?

BTW, People here generally like users to post code as copyable Mathematica code as well as images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site, helpful

See ParametricPlot

Without knowing reasonable values of your parameters it is difficult to guess.
This might be what you are looking for
a=1;\[Beta]=2;\[Alpha]=3;\[Lambda]=1;\[Delta]=1/2;
S=a M^2+\[Beta]+\[Alpha] Log[a M^2];
t=\[Lambda]^5 M^5(3+\[Lambda]^2 M^2)/(3 \[Delta](1+\[Lambda]^2 M^2)^2);
ParametricPlot[{S,t},{M,-3,3}]


Your arguments to ParametricPlot are reversed.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

a = 1; β = 2; α = 3; λ = 1; δ = 1/2;

eqns = {
  t == λ^5 M^5 (3 + λ^2 M^2)/(3 δ (1 + λ^2 M^2)^2),
  S == a M^2 + β + α Log[a M^2]}

(* {t == (2 M^5 (3 + M^2))/(3 (1 + M^2)^2), S == 2 + M^2 + 3 Log[M^2]} *)

As suggested by Bill you can use ParametricPlot
ParametricPlot[eqns[[All, 2]], {M, -3, 3},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, S}),
 ColorFunction -> Function[{t, S, M}, ColorData["Rainbow"][M]],
 PlotLegends ->
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-3, 3}},
   LegendMarkerSize -> 240,
   LegendLabel -> Style["M", 14]],
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-6, Automatic}}]


Alternatively, Solve for S while eliminating M
sol = SolveValues[eqns, S, {M}, Reals][[1]]

(* 2 + 3 Log[Root[-3 t - 6 t #1^2 - 3 t #1^4 + 6 #1^5 + 2 #1^7 &, 1]^2] + 
 Root[-3 t - 6 t #1^2 - 3 t #1^4 + 6 #1^5 + 2 #1^7 &, 1]^2 *)

The Root expressions when given arguments, evaluate to numbers
Plot[sol, {t, -20, 20},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, S})]


